# Trying to run an app on my emulator but getting this error:

Tags: kotlin

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values:

```
 The minCompileSdk (34) specified in a
 dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
 is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-33).
 Dependency: androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0-alpha05.
 AAR metadata file: C:\Users\knewm\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\8e60de917c7b0452216b48af827ec783\transformed\jetified-activity-1.8.0-alpha05\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
```

I tried updating my dependcies and SDKs under build.gradle(app). I also changed from 34 to 33 in the project structure.

Comment: Add your app's `build.gradle` to catch issue easily.